# Make sudo ask for my password again?

Tags: linux, sudo

Is there any way to make `sudo` forget my password instantly instead of remembering it for 5 minutes?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Edit your sudoers file by running `visudo` as root.

Look for the `Defaults` line, and add `timestamp_timeout=0` to the end.

Eg.

`Defaults         env_reset,timestamp_timeout=0`

(Edited: Sorry, got confused, had the wrong keyword. Fixed. )

Answer (score 49):

If you just want to make sudo ask again for the current session

```
sudo -k
```